# Why Magento2.2 create "_cache" Directory under pub/static/_cache

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento-2.0

Just want to know about **_cache Directory** which is generating under `[root]/pub/static/`

I have noticed that once upgrades, compile & deployed command done through **CLI** then **_cache directory is creating**.

**What is the purpose of this _cache directory?**

**Is it Specific for Production mode?**

**Will it help to increase performance of JS and CSS?**

**Thanx in Advance!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**_cache** folder at   `pub/static` is created when you **enable CSS/Js minify or merge**.

During Static content deply if this **merge/minify** setting enables then the merge and minify CSS and js is generates at the store at **pub/static/_cache** and it creates Website Speed.